# Reset "natural" orientation of part to 0,0,0 without moving it

Tags: roblox

I downloaded several sword models from the marketplace. Then, in workspace, oriented them all the same (eg handles all on same side, blade flat to ground). I then moved them into ReplicatedStorage. Later, I clone them and place them back in the workspace. 
When they return to workspace, they are back to their original (ie marketplace) orientation. I have to rotate them again in code.

Is there a way to reset the "natural" orientation of a part/mesh?

By this I mean;

1. Create or download model from market place
2. rotate/transform to desired position
3. do "something" which resets the orientation to 0, 0, 0 WITHOUT visually rotating the model.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have set the sword model's [PrimaryPart](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Model/PrimaryPart) to the handle. To change the PrimaryPart's CFrame as well as all the other parts in the model relative to it, we use the [:SetPrimaryPartCFrame()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Model/SetPrimaryPartCFrame) function

```
sword:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(0, 0, 0)) -- 0, 0, 0 as in X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0
```

Now, let's say you aren't satisfied with the orientation of the model. We can fix this by "multiplying" the location CFrame with an orientation CFrame ([CFrame.fromOrientation()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame))

Orientation CFrames are expressed in radians, so in order to convert radians to degrees, we use the [math.rad()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/math) function

In this code example we set the location to 0, 0, 0 and orientation to 0, 0, 90

```
sword:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(0, 0, 0) * CFrame.fromOrientation(0, 0, math.rad(90)))
```

The only thing left to do is to experiment with various orientation X, Y and Z values until you get the correct result